# Difference between <update> and <reference> handle in magento layout files

Tags: layout, xml

I am bit confused in this two handle like when to use this two tags. Please clearfy for me like when to use this two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Reference**

This is used to make a reference to an current existing block in the layout xml. Say you want to change a template of a block you would first reference it and then call set template. Or if you wanted to add some new javascript to the header.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>something/new.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Update**

This is used to add a complete layout handle inside another one. For example if you had the layout handle `test_handle` and wanted to include the handle `catalog_product_view` you would do the following.

```
<test_handle>
    <update name="catalog_product_view" />
</test_handle>
```

In this case the `test_handle` and the `catalog_product_view` handle would be exactly the same and include the same blocks.

Comment: ..Thank you very much. It is really good answer which i was looking for. I have used sometimes, I was bit confused. As I understood to update the block we <reference> or edit the block and to just get the copy of the block we use the update handle .. thanks

Comment: @MagentoBoy yeah think of reference like a rewrite of what is already there and update as a copy to be used for something else. If it is the answer you are looking for you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks... Can I add you on any social website .. like fb or G+